# mysqli extension missing - phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I re-installed mysql-server and phpmyadmin and am confronted with an error regarding mysqli extension is missing.

I already tried to re-install mysqli like:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall php-mysql
```

I tried to edit the `php.ini` file in `/etc/php/7.4/apache2` and un-comment `extension=mysqli` and changed it to `/usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli.so` but this didn't work, either.

PHP-Version: 7.4.3
Ubuntu: 20.04
MySQL: 8.x

EDIT: `sudo apt list --installed | grep php` shows:

```
libapache2-mod-php7.4/focal-updates,focal-security,now 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4 amd64  [installiert]
php-bz2/focal,now 2:7.4+75 all  [installiert]
php-common/focal,now 2:75 all  [installiert]
php-curl/focal,now 2:7.4+75 all  [installiert]
php-gd/focal,now 2:7.4+75 all  [installiert]
php-google-recaptcha/focal,now 1.2.3-1 all  [installiert]
php-json/focal,now 2:7.4+75 all  [installiert]
php-mbstring/focal,now 2:7.4+75 all  [installiert]
php-mysql/focal,now 2:7.4+75 all  [installiert]
php-phpmyadmin-motranslator/focal,now 5.0.0-1 all  [installiert]
php-phpmyadmin-shapefile/focal,now 2.1-3 all  [installiert]
php-phpmyadmin-sql-parser/focal,now 4.6.1-2 all  [installiert]
php-phpseclib/focal,now 2.0.23-2 all  [installiert]
php-psr-cache/focal,now 1.0.1-2 all  [installiert]
php-psr-container/focal,now 1.0.0-2 all  [installiert]
php-psr-log/focal,now 1.1.2-1 all  [installiert]
php-symfony-cache-contracts/focal,now 1.1.8-1 all  [installiert]
php-symfony-cache/focal,now 4.3.8+dfsg-1ubuntu1 all  [installiert]
php-symfony-expression-language/focal,now 4.3.8+dfsg-1ubuntu1 all [installiert]
php-symfony-service-contracts/focal,now 1.1.8-1 all  [installiert]
php-symfony-var-exporter/focal,now 4.3.8+dfsg-1ubuntu1 all [installiert]
php-tcpdf/focal,now 6.3.5+dfsg1-1 all  [installiert]
php-twig-extensions/focal,now 1.5.4-1 all  [installiert]
php-twig/focal,now 2.12.5-1 all  [installiert]
php-xml/focal,now 2:7.4+75 all  [installiert]
php-zip/focal,now 2:7.4+75 all  [installiert]
php7.4-bz2/focal-updates,focal-security,now 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4 amd64  [installiert]
php7.4-cli/focal-updates,focal-security,now 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4 amd64  [installiert]
php7.4-common/focal-updates,focal-security,now 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4 amd64  [installiert]
php7.4-curl/focal-updates,focal-security,now 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4 amd64  [installiert]
php7.4-gd/focal-updates,focal-security,now 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4 amd64  [installiert]
php7.4-json/focal-updates,focal-security,now 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4 amd64  [installiert]
php7.4-mbstring/focal-updates,focal-security,now 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4 amd64  [installiert]
php7.4-mysql/focal-updates,focal-security,now 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4 amd64  [installiert]
php7.4-opcache/focal-updates,focal-security,now 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4 amd64  [installiert]
php7.4-readline/focal-updates,focal-security,now 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4 amd64  [installiert]
php7.4-xml/focal-updates,focal-security,now 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4 amd64  [installiert]
php7.4-zip/focal-updates,focal-security,now 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4 amd64  [installiert]
php7.4/focal-updates,focal-security,now 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4 all  [installiert]
php/focal,now 2:7.4+75 all  [installiert]
phpmyadmin/focal,now 4:4.9.5+dfsg1-2 all  [installiert]
```

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   30984 Okt  6 15:47 bz2.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   43272 Okt  6 15:47 calendar.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14600 Okt  6 15:47 ctype.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  104712 Okt  6 15:47 curl.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  166152 Okt  6 15:47 dom.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   92424 Okt  6 15:47 exif.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  162056 Okt  6 15:47 ffi.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5744904 Okt  6 15:47 fileinfo.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   67848 Okt  6 15:47 ftp.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  117000 Okt  6 15:47 gd.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   18696 Okt  6 15:47 gettext.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   51464 Okt  6 15:47 iconv.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  498016 Okt  6 15:47 intl.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   47368 Okt  6 15:47 json.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1053696 Okt  6 15:47 mbstring.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  145672 Okt  6 15:47 mysqli.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  260088 Okt  6 15:47 mysqlnd.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  555688 Okt  6 15:47 opcache.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   35080 Okt  6 15:47 pdo_mysql.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  112904 Okt  6 15:47 pdo.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  280840 Okt  6 15:47 phar.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   43272 Okt  6 15:47 posix.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   39176 Okt  6 15:47 readline.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14600 Okt  6 15:47 shmop.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   55560 Okt  6 15:47 simplexml.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  100616 Okt  6 15:47 sockets.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   22792 Okt  6 15:47 sysvmsg.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14600 Okt  6 15:47 sysvsem.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   18696 Okt  6 15:47 sysvshm.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   26888 Okt  6 15:47 tokenizer.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   39176 Okt  6 15:47 xmlreader.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   55560 Okt  6 15:47 xml.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   51464 Okt  6 15:47 xmlwriter.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   35080 Okt  6 15:47 xsl.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   71944 Okt  6 15:47 zip.so
```

Still struggling with this.

Comment: How did you install php (what command) and what php packages are present on your system? Do a `sudo apt list --installed |grep php` or something. I just ask as on my system I have versioned packages installed such as `php7.4-mysql` and not `php-mysql` I don't really know why, just thinking that may be a factor in your installation and you need to install/re-install the versioned package.

Comment: @codlord I edited the question. I must admit, I have no idea about that. So could you take a look?

Comment: I would update your question with the error you are getting, what error log is showing the error regarding extension missing and what is the exact error?

And you do have both `php-mysql` and `php7.4-mysql` installed. But I don't know why or which is being used etc. You could try re-installing `php7.4-mysql` then restart mysql & apache perhaps. Personally I did not have to do any tweaks to enable extensions I just installed `libapache2-mod-php7.4 php7.4-mysql php7.4-zip php7.4-bz2 php7.4-mbstring` then installed phpmyadmin, created/setup phpmyadmin database and restarted apache.

Comment: @codlord I tried to also re-install php7.4 mysql, restarted the services and cleared browser cache. But didin't change a thing. The error logs of mysql error logs doesn't show the error. It's just when displaying phpmyadmin. The mysqli is missing.

Comment: Have you tried all the suggestions here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769148/extension-mysqli-is-missing-phpmyadmin-doesnt-work

Comment: @codlord sadly yes. Also just removed phpmyadmin and re-installed everything..

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of `ls -AlF /usr/lib/php/20190902/`? I wonder if this might be a file permissions issue.

Comment: @Matigo And is it?

Answer (score 1):

I hope my successful answer helps someone in recent times as I had to try many mix-and-matches and then found it:

This solution worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop with **PHP v7.4**, **PHP v8.0.7** and **MySQL v8.0.25** setup.

What I did was edited `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/php/8.0/apache2/php.ini` files and replaced
`extension=mysqli.so`
with
`extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli.so`
in both the files.

Later, restarted both of these (PHP and MySQL) by `sudo systemctl restart apache2` and `sudo systemctl restart mysql`. Refreshed Chrome, and phpMyAdmin responded with the login screen.

(**PS:** Please check if you have `/usr/lib/php/20200930/mysqli.so` file as well. I tested this as it looked newer by directory date, and this too worked in both the PHP files as `extension=/usr/lib/php/20200930/mysqli.so`)

Comment: Ok but where did you get this file from? `/usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli.so`

Answer (score 0):

I solve it based on this https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16183
PHP7.2

phpmyadmin     4:4.6.6-5ubu all 
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.41

When I run sudo apt install php-mysqli

I got the list to choose

php8.2-mysql 8.2.3-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
    php8.1-mysql 8.1.16+repack-  1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
    php8.0-mysql 1:8.0.28-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
    php7.4-mysql 1:7.4.33-5+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
    php7.3-mysql 7.3.33-10+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
    php7.2-mysql 7.2.34-38+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
    php7.1-mysql 7.1.33-52+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
    php7.0-mysql 7.0.33-65+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
    php5.6-mysql 5.6.40-65+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

I did not have to modify.ini